# Replace value in DataFrame when value not empty

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to replace the values from a DataFrame column with values from a List.

How do I replace them only when the value in the list is not an empty string ?

Both are ordered the same way :

```
    Dataframe                  List

ID     Date                  UpdatedDate
1      19/04/2022            20/10/2022
2      12/07/2022                  
3      27/09/2022            03/10/2022
4      11/05/2022            14/10/2022
5      04/10/2022                  
6      02/08/2022            19/10/2022
```

I want this to become a single dataframe with the updated dates.

```
ID     Date
1      20/10/2022
2      12/07/2022                  
3      03/10/2022
4      14/10/2022
5      04/10/2022                  
6      19/10/2022
```

Any suggestions? Much appreciated.

Comment: Is your list actually a list? or a series?

Comment: It is a list, with either a date or empty string

Comment: ah ok, let me update my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you list is a list that looks like this:

lst = ['20/10/2022', '', '03/10/2022', '14/10/2022', '', '19/10/2022']

You can add that to your df as a new column like this:

```
df['lst'] = lst

         Date         lst
0  19/04/2022  20/10/2022
1  12/07/2022            
2  27/09/2022  03/10/2022
3  11/05/2022  14/10/2022
4  04/10/2022            
5  02/08/2022  19/10/2022
```

you can then use [`.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) on the lst column to replace the empty strings with np.nan (may need to add `import numpy as np` for this). Then use [`.fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) to fill in the gaps in lst with Date:

```
df['Date'] = df['lst'].replace('', np.nan).fillna(df['Date'])

         Date         lst
0  20/10/2022  20/10/2022
1  12/07/2022            
2  03/10/2022  03/10/2022
3  14/10/2022  14/10/2022
4  04/10/2022            
5  19/10/2022  19/10/2022
```

Then drop the 'lst' column to get the final df:

```
df = df.drop('lst', axis=1)

         Date
0  20/10/2022
1  12/07/2022
2  03/10/2022
3  14/10/2022
4  04/10/2022
5  19/10/2022
```